# SQL if matched update if not matched then insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Please help with this one...
I'm trying to implement this SQL code in VB , code works for update but not for insert ...

```
merge into anamneza a
using (select ana_id from anamneza where ana_id = 2) e 
on (a.ana_id = e.ana_id)
when matched then 
update set a.ana_kupanje = 'da' 
when not matched then
insert (ana_rb,ana_id,ana_kupanje,ana_kosa,ana_brijanje,ana_zubi,ana_nokti,ana_odjeca,ana_koza,ana_dek_rizik,ana_dek_rizik_gdje,ana_dek_postojeci,ana_dek_post_gdje,ana_pokretnost,ana_kolica,ana_pomagala,azurirao,datumazur)
values (1,1,'da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','veki',getdate());
```

First i wrote it in a SQLQuery and executed it and it says 
(0 row(s) affected)

But when I insert that row and it has id=1 and change that select thati it matches ana_id = 1 it says (1 row(s) affected);

Why insert statement doesn't work???

Comment: [Please reconsider using `MERGE` for this at all](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: Does it return an error?

Comment: Nope no error just 0 rows affected and when i do the insert manually on execution it updates field... wierd

Comment: In case the link from Aaron B dissapears; merge has bugs and a few are marked as won't fix.

Comment: I think this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794870/using-sql-server-merge-command-with-same-source-target-table

Comment: Yes but still doesn't solve my question cause everything is done like there and doesn't work... why insert wouldn't work when I change it to insert into anamneza values (2,2,'da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','da','veki',getdate()); It inserts with no problems

Comment: "everything is done like there" - look closer; your `MERGE` matches the one in the _question_; please make it match the one in the _answer_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in [Using SQL Server MERGE command with same source & target table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794870/using-sql-server-merge-command-with-same-source-target-table), replace line 2 of your `MERGE` statement by:

```
using (
    select 1 as ana_rb, 1 as ana_id,
           'da' as ana_kupanje, 'da' as ana_kosa, 'da' as ana_brijanje,
           'da' as ana_zubi, 'da' as ana_nokti, 'da' as ana_odjeca,
           'da' as ana_koza, 'da' as ana_dek_rizik, 'da' as ana_dek_rizik_gdje,
           'da' as ana_dek_postojeci, 'da' as ana_dek_post_gdje,
           'da' as ana_pokretnost, 'da' as ana_kolica, 'da' as ana_pomagala,
           'veki' as azurirao, getdate() as datumazur
) e
```

**NOTE:** make sure the values match those in the `INSERT` part!