# How to use MERGE's 'When not matched' to insert a new record in same table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to do an upsert into a single table using SQL Server's Merge statement.

```
declare @Mergeoutput table (action varchar(50))

declare variables ...

MERGE Usertable AS target
using (Select .... from Usertable where filter conditions using variables)
    as Source (column names..)
on source.... = target.... (multiple statements)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET....

WHEN NOT MATCHED by target THEN
  INSERT (...)
     VALUES (...)
output $action into @Mergeoutput;
select * from @Mergeoutput
```

The update works if there's a match but the insert doesn't happen when there's no match. @Mergeout is empty. My update and insert statements should take action on one row. How does Merge work when the using statement is an empty set and I want to insert a new row?

**Update:**
This is the SQL to run everything. I expected @Mergeoutput to return 'Insert' and the Person table to have a new row.

```
Create table Person
(
  name varchar(20)
)

declare @Mergeoutput table (action varchar(50))

declare @newName varchar(20)

select @newName  = 'John'

MERGE Person AS target
using (Select name from Person where name= 'John')
    as Source (name)
on source.name = target.name

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET name = 'John2'

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (name)
     VALUES ('John')
output $action into @Mergeoutput;
select * from @Mergeoutput

select * from person
```

Comment: Please preapare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample table and desired output. It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. It looks like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10795503/5070879)

Comment: sqlfiddle kept giving me an error with the merge statement. See my update above.

Comment: Looks like no one caught the fact the I did mention that the source is an empty set and therefore the merge will not insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, your [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb510625.aspx) statement would look like this:

```
MERGE INTO @Person AS target
USING
(
    SELECT name 
    FROM @Person 
    WHERE <.......>
) AS Source
ON source.name = target.name

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET name = Source.name

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (name)
VALUES (Source.name)
;
```

Note, that I take values from `Source` and insert them into `Target`.

> **WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] THEN**
>
> Specifies that a row is inserted into target_table for every row
>   returned by `<table_source> ON <merge_search_condition>` that does not
>   match a row in target_table, but does satisfy an additional search
>   condition, if present. The values to insert are specified by the
>   `<merge_not_matched>` clause.

So, if your `Source` is empty, nothing will be inserted, regardless of the `ON` criteria.

It is not really clear what overall logic you are trying to achieve, but it seems that you may need to have some extra logic in the `Source` query.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the Merge statement fully.  USING (
    SELECT @NewName) AS Source worked. The idea is that source can't be empty for the insert to work. I might just use an old fashioned if.. insert else update.

Comment: `MERGE` works great when you have two different tables and you need to sync them. Using `MERGE` with the same table sounds strange to me. In your case it may be easier and better to use explicit `IF` as you said. It depends on the logic in `IF` and whether you have single or multiple rows to update and insert.